# HTML 5 Max and Min error message localization

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have aps.net MVC project, where I have to set the range of date inputs on user side, I am doing this manually with jquery scripts. Today found html 5 attributes min and max, which work great with restriction date values, the error is shown in `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` element, but the only trouble is - I cant localize it.
Code i have now for my date field:

```
<td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.EndDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = datepicker" ", id = "EditorForTillDate", max@="20.12.2018" } })</td>
<td style="width:10%">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EndDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</td>
```

and model:

```
[Display(Name = "end_date", ResourceType = typeof(Localization))]
[DateWorkExpAttribute(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Localization), ErrorMessageResourceName = "error_end_date_invalid")]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndDate { get; set; }
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP Net MVC - Localization of Validation Messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353265/asp-net-mvc-localization-of-validation-messages)

Comment: How do you get your errors if you use `max` and `min` attributes? Show your whole view with scripts and controller

Comment: @teovankot, `max` and `min` are browser validation attributes. The script doesn't require them to perform validation. Consider this: `<input type="number" min="0" max="5" name="atMost5" />`

Comment: @Charles i know. My question is - what's OP actually try to localize? I don't see anything in code that he posted. That's why i want to see controller and View

Answer (score 0):

In `ValidationMessageFor` will work when in your model add`Date annotations` for your example will be:

```
[Display (Name = "end_date" ResourceType = typeof (Localization))]
[DateWorkExpAttribute (ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Localization), ErrorMessageResourceName = "error_end_date_invalid")]
[StringLength (255 MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "* Part descriptions must be between 3 and 255 characters in length.")]
[Required (ErrorMessage = "This value is empty !! It's not correctly")]
public Nullable <System.DateTime> EndDate {get; set; }
```

For Html 5 attribute `ValidationMessegeFor` will not work because it is only HTML 5 attribute the client site. `ValidationMassegeFor` will set when controller post method  return `ModelState.IsValid` false (It is mechanism the server side).